# magento 301 redirects not working through URL Rewrite

Tags: magento, redirect

I want to redirect some links with new links of my magento site. Here is what I want :
Old Link : `http://dressat.se/sv/atlas-design.html`
New Link : `http://dressat.se/index.php/varumarken/atlas-design.html`

In Magento admin panel > Catalog > URL rewrite Managment. I have put links like this :
ID Path : `sv/atlas-design.html`
Request Path : `sv/atlas-design.html`
Target Path : `index.php/varumarken/atlas-design.html`

But its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing index.php from the target link and also enable url rewrite in the system/Configuration/web.. Here set "Use Web Server Rewrites" to Yes and try once again

Comment: I have did both steps but still not working.

Comment: is 'varumarken' is an active category?

Comment: yes ofcourse, it is an active category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 301 redirection in your htaccess file in root directory.

```
Redirect 301 /sv/atlas-design.html http://dressat.se/index.php/varumarken/atlas-design.html
```

This will help you.